# AngularJS - Change checkbox status on selected row with Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

what I'm trying to do is to change the checkbox to checked/unchecked when I click on any part of the row. Also I'm changing the color of the selected rows.
Here is what I got:

player.component.html:

```
<!-- Table showing players -->
<tbody *ngFor="let volunteer of volunteers; let i = index">
  <tr class="margin" (click)="setClickedRow(i)" [class.active]="selectedRows[i]==true">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">{{player.name}}</td>
    <td>{{player.number}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

player.component.ts:

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedRows: boolean[] = [false, false, false, false];
    setClickedRow: Function;

    player = [
        { name: 'Jaden', number: '2' },
        { name: 'Mickey', number: '10' },
        { name: 'Dexter', number: '22' },
        { name: 'Pedro', number: '11' },
    ];

    constructor() {

        this.setClickedRow = function (index) {
            if (!this.selectedRows[index]) {
                this.selectedRows[index] = true;
            }
            else {
                this.selectedRows[index] = false;
            }
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I want the checkbox to change no matter what part of the row I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the `checked` property?

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="selectedRows[i]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove

```
this.setClickedRow = function(index){...
```

from inside of the constructor.
Then set is as:

```
setClickedRow (index) {
  console.log("Clicked")
  this.selectedRows[index]=!!this.selectedRows[index];
};
```

Now check the console on row click.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9enb5w)

Comment: This helped me, but wasn't exactly what I was looking for. Thank you tho, was helpful